# MUDAR O PATH WINDOWS 7

Tags: windows, path, flutter

Olá, para inicializar meu curso de Flutter, um dos requisitos é mudar o Path do windows para 'flutter\bin'. O problema é que meu PATH já possui um valor e quando clico em "editar", não aparece uma lista da qual eu possa apenas inserir o PATH. 
Teria problema excluir o conteúdo da variável atual do PATH e inserir o do Flutter?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sim, teria problema. Tu deves inserir os valores separando-os por `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, teria problema - algum(s) programas podem parar de funcionar com isso (aparentemente, o `npm`, no teu caso).

Tu tens que inserir o valor separando-o dos demais com `;`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode separar os valores do PATH usando um `;`

Ficaria assim:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\src\flutter\bin
```

Lembrando apenas de se certificar que o flutter está neste diretório `src`

Caso queira visualizar seu **PATH** completo no windows, você pode executar o comando `PATH` direto na linha de comando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]